# Display TomTom map with folium

Tags: python, openstreetmap, folium, tomtom

I am starting data scientist and I am doing a benchmark for maps. 
I would like to visualize the **TomTom map API** in Jupyter notebook with **folium** to compare it with **OpenStreetMap**. Openstreet map is supported by folium so that is easy. This code is doing the trick:

```
import folium 

OSM_map = folium.Map(location=[45.523, -122.675],
                    zoom_start=13,
                    tiles="OpenStreetMap")
```

Now, I would like to do the same with the TomTom maps API. On developer.tomtom.com I find that this is the request URL:

```
https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/0/0/0.png?view=Unified&key=*****
```

So I thought to implement this in folium. I don't get an error message but it is just displaying a gray map.

```
TomTom_map = folium.Map(
   location=[45.523, -122.675],
   zoom_start=10,
   tiles='http://{s}.api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
   API_key = 'xxxxxx',
   attr='TomTom')
```

I follow literally the example of the folium documentation but it does not work. Anyone knows how to solve this? That would be great :). Cheers.

Comment: I haven't used a custom tileset before, but you could try to pass the API key in the tiles arg e.g. `tiles='http://{s}.api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?view=Unified&key=*****'`  Also, you would omit the `API_key` arg in this scenario

Comment: I agree with Bob. Cloudmade API key's parameter name is **apikey** and for TomTom it is **key**.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is doing the trick! :)

Comment: Good deal.  I'll have to explore the custom tileset options soon

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Bob and szogoon,

It works now! I replaced the code with:

```
import folium 

TomTom_map = folium.Map(
    location=[45.523, -122.675],
    zoom_start=10,
    tiles= 'http://{s}.api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png? 
    view=Unified&key=********',
    attr='TomTom')
```